# Accessing NSUserDefaults from Airwatch

Tags: ios, react-native, airwatch

I am wondering if there is anything going wrong here that anyone can help with.

Airwatch allows us to configure an app config for each “assignment” group of an app. Config is entered as key-value pairs, and we can also use placeholders for which AirWatch will insert lookup values.

I have created a test config on one of the dev assignment groups as follows:

[image]

Then in my React Native code i have access these key values like so....

```
import { Settings } from 'react-native';

const deviceName = Settings?.get?.('DeviceName');
const deviceUdid = Settings?.get?.('DeviceUdid');
const deviceSerialNumber = Settings?.get?.('DeviceSerialNumber');
```

The values are coming back undefined. Firstly, is there a way I can test locally to rule out the front end being the issue?
Or, am I doing something wrong here entirely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the values directly. They are added to a dictionary under the key `com.apple.configuration.managed`

See https://www.appconfig.org/ios.html

```
const mangedConfig = Settings?.get?.('com.apple.configuration.managed')

const deviceName = managedConfig['DeviceName']
```

Comment: when I change the device name in the device settings the new value is not updating in Settings.get(). I tried reopening the app. the only way I could read the new device name is to install again from the app catalog.